# Unable to get value of the property 'DataTable': object is null or undefined

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-visualization

IE failing with google visualisation api

my javascript runs on domcententloaded, but fails right at the start when trying to use the.

```
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function drawChart() {
        alert("1");
        google.load('visualization', '1.0', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
        // Create the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(); //this fails
        ...});
```

i'm using ie9

Answer (score 0):

the google.visualization object is not again loaded ;)

Try this :

```
function onready_visualization() {
 var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(); //this fails
};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function drawChart() {
        alert("1");
        google.load('visualization', '1.0', { 'packages': ['corechart'], 'callback': onready_visualization });
        // Create the data table.
        //...
});
```

Comment: gives Error: 'data' is undefined

Comment: all your code must be placed in the "onready_visualization" function.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, there is no good reason to wait for document load to load the Visualization API (and can actually cause problems, as the google loader behaves strangely when called from other functions).  Put your visualization code in a function and use the callback from the Google loader to draw your visualization:

```
function drawVisualization () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    // rest of visualization code
}
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart'], callback: drawVisualization});
```